# Why is there a python 3.x branch when we have continued development on the 2.x branch?

Tags: python

The Python 2.x environment is stable and well-utilized by the current python community. And yet there is also a python 3.x branch of the language.

Why have we started a python 3.x branch? Does that imply that we are going to deprecate the 2.x branch anytime soon?

Can an experienced python developer explain the differences between the two and offer the best choice for a newbie who wants to learn the language?

If python 3.x is gonna be used longer, Are we solving the existing problems in 2.x like,
GIL issue for multithreading support?

Sorry if this question seems really basic but I would really like to learn!

Comment: In principle, for the same reason there is 2.7 despite the existence of 2.6. Everything else is just due to the backwards incompatibility of 3.0 and the developers' policy on backwards compatibility.

Comment: The 2.x series is pretty much done - it has reached a local optimum. The 3.x series is a rewrite of a lot of the functionality and includes some design changes for a new major version. This includes changes to the grammar itself, how memory management, etc is done under the hood, etc etc

Comment: Python 3 is intentionally **not** backwards compatible. No future major versions of Python 2 will be released. Take a look at [Python's 2 vs 3 explanation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

Comment: I understand,in this above link was mentioned trying to make the compatibility better in 3.x than 2.x.Is the 3.x branch is gonna give support to solve GIL issue kind of?

Comment: @Nava that's a completely different question. **There isn't any plan to remove the GIL**. I don't really understand all the fuss about the GIL. In almost all cases the GIL is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 2.x series is already deprecated in the sense that there will be no version 2.8 - 2.7 was the last 2.x major version.

The reason for the 2 to 3 change is because the 3.x branch makes certain backwards-incompatible changes (e.g. differentiating `bytes` and `str`, making `print()` a function rather than a statement, et cetera). This breaks compatibility with programs written for Python 2.x and as such requires special handling.

All new feature development is occurring in the 3.x branch. Some changes are being backported to 2.7.x versions, but that will only happen for so long - eventually, Python 2.7 will stop being maintained.

Comment: Don't forget that some changes are still being backported from 3.x to 2.7 though!

Comment: @ardentsonata: there won't be any more backporting of features, only bugfixes.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 breaks compatibility with Python 2.

This is pretty normal release management. When incompatible changes are introduced, previous major release branch is maintained for a period of time, sometimes a long one, alongside the new branch.